# WebRTC video not being able to see

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

How do i enable WebRTC video(and audio too) viewing in browsers like Chrome and Mozilla.

The code i am using is this

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title> WebRTC</title>

        </head>
        <body>
        <video id="peer2-to-peer1" autoplay controls style="width:40%;"></video>

            <script src="script.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

javascript file :

```
navigator.getUserMedia ||
      (navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {

        navigator.getUserMedia({

          audio: true
        }, function(localMediaStream) {alert('in');
      var video = document.querySelector('video');
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
      video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
         // Do something with the video here.
      };
   }, onError);
    } else {
        alert('getUserMedia is not supported in this browser.');
    }

    function onSuccess() {
        alert('Successful!');
    }

    function onError() {
        alert('There has been a problem retrieving the streams - did you allow access?');
    }
```

BUT ,

i am getting an error because onSuccess function is'nt called.

LINK :

http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/get-started-webrtc-1132857

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that you are not requiring video on your `getUserMedia`. Your params suggest only audio is required no `video: true` parameter in your call. Yes, `onSuccess` is never called but that does not matter as you have the callback inside of the function call itself. To call `onSucess` your syntax is something like:

`getUserMedia({"audio": true, "video": true}, onSuccess, onFailure);`

Secondly, have `onSuccess` take a parameter, which will be the media stream. You would need to attach the stream src to the video src object in the `onSuccess` function if you want it to do anything with the media stream.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `onSuccess()` you call this:

```
function(localMediaStream) {alert('in');
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
     // Do something with the video here.
  };
```

}

`onSuccess()` is simply never been called.

It is furthermore necessary to load the files from a web server (e.g. have a server running on localhost). As the tutorial states, accessing the html file on your local hard drive won't work.

Comment: i m still getting nothing in chrome(version 36), on error function called in chrome(34).

Comment: can you post the errors you get (if there are in your browser's console)? and do you get the files from a server? Just opening the files with a browser will not work.

Comment: we are storing files in the local machine...and i am following the link :   http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/get-started-webrtc-1132857

Comment: it is necessary to get the files from a server, so have server running on localhost and make the files accessible there. When you have the files simply on your hard drive (e.g. file:///C:/...) it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://yashsinha.com/webrtc/Demo%201/)

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Record and Play Simple Messages</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Demo for GetUserMedia()</p>
    <video id="localStream"></video>
    <script type="text/javascript" type="javascript" src="./js/script.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');

navigator.getUserMedia =
    navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia;

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL;

function errorCallback(error) {
    console.log('An error occurred: ' + error.code);
}

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(stream){
        if (video.mozSrcObject !== undefined) {
            video.mozSrcObject = stream;
        } else {
            video.src = (window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)) || stream;
        }
        video.play();
    }, errorCallback);
} else {
    console.log('getUserMedia() not supported in this browser.');
}
```